# how to get ride of equal column in our panda data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have three data frames with sizes of df1=(176, 5766)    df2=(8, 5766)    df3=(16, 5766), in my columns despite the different columns name there are similar data values (all the columns in each three are equal), but when I using for example

```
df1.T.drop_duplicates().T 
df2.T.drop_duplicates().T 
df3.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

although it must create the same output column but it convert the
df1=(176, 581)    df2=(8, 632)    df3=(16, 622)
how I can get ride of this?

Comment: do you mean that you would like to keep the columns that exist in all 3 dataframes and remove the rest from all the dataframes? So essentially you are left with the same amount of columns in all of them?

Comment: no, I mean I want to remove similar columns in terms of values column (not the name column), because all three data frames are similar columns but just the row numbers are different. but as you are waiting, after removing the similar columns by the above method  they must be same column number in output but it is not?

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax:** df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep=’first’, inplace=False)

**Parameters:**

- subset:

Subset takes a column or list of column label. It’s default value is none. After passing columns, it will consider them only for duplicates.

- keep:

keep is to control how to consider duplicate value. It has only three distinct values - first, last and false. default is ‘first’. ‘first’, it considers the first value as unique and rest of the same values as duplicate.

- inplace:

Boolean values, removes rows with duplicates if True.

```
# dropping duplicate values
df1.drop_duplicates(keep=False,inplace=True)
df2.drop_duplicates(keep=False,inplace=True)
df3.drop_duplicates(keep=False,inplace=True)
```

Comment: thank you promila but I want to remove the similar column, not the raw one, you recommend do not remove the similar one in all three?